# arraylist(javaObect) iteration in velocity template

Tags: foreach, velocity

I have two tables Author, Books. And POJOs, .hbm.xml for each of the tables. I wrote a select query which gives me some details from both the tables.

```
select A.id.BookNum,A.id.AuthorName,B.id.DatePublished,B.id.Price
,B.id.Condition,B.id.BookBought from Author A, Book B where
B.id.Condition == 'NEW' and  A.id.BookNum = A.id.BookNum order by
A.id.AuthorName;
```

I have got the results, and having it stored in ArrayList. [UnApprovedBookList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi1r0.jpg) When i try to display this in velocity template i am not able to iterate this. I have my POJOs as Author, Book which has getter()/ Setter() for AuthorId and BookId respectively and AuthorId, BookId which has the getters/ setters for fields in it.

```
    public class Book implements java.io.Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private BookId id;
        public Book (){ }
        public Book (BookId id){this.id = id;}
        public BookId getId(){return id;}
        public void setId(BookId id) {this.id = id;}
    }
```

and my BookId with getters/ setters for the fields in it, basically all the table columns.

```
public class BookId implements java.io.Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private BookNum;
        public BookId (){   }
        public String getBookNumid() {return BookNum;}
        public void setBookNum(String bookNum) {bookNum= bookNum;}
      }
```

And my hbm as below:

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.bookStore.hibernate.dao.Book" table="BOOK" schema="ORG">
            <composite-id name="id" class="com.bookStore.hibernate.dao.BookId">
                <key-property name="BookNum" type="string">
                    <column name="SH_BOOK_NUM" length="17" />
                </key-property>
                <key-property name="DatePublished" type="date">
                    <column name="SH_DATE_PUB" length="13" />
                </key-property>
                <key-property name="Price" type="int">
                    <column name="SH_PRICE" length="5" />
                </key-property>
                <key-property name="Condition" type="string">
                    <column name="SH_CONDITION" length="10" />
                </key-property>
                <key-property name="BookBought " type="date">
                    <column name="SH_BOOK_BOUGHT" length="13" />
                </key-property>
            </composite-id>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

And I am finding it difficult when I try to iterate and display in Velocity. my code snippet as below:

```
      #foreach($unApprovedBook in $unApprovedBookList)
           <input type="text" id="bookNum" value="$unApprovedBook.getId().getBookNumid()">
         #set($i = $i + 1)
```

By doing so i am seeing  ***$unApprovedBook.getId().getBookNumid()*** in UI
if I change the code to:

```
#foreach($unApprovedBook in $unApprovedBookList)
<input type="text" id="bookNum" value="$unApprovedBook">
#set($i = $i + 1)
```

I am seeing: **[Ljava.lang.Object;@3160316** in UI.
Please let me know what how can I iterate my javaobject in Velocity.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBrYQ.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Way:

You should use property expression `$unApprovedBook.id.BookNum`. Try To follow Java naming convention.

```
  <input type="text" id="bookNum" value="${unApprovedBook.id.BookNum}">
```

Comment: It is not working either. I have changed my code to: <input type="text" id="bookNum" value="$unApproved.id.IProflKey">,  and the output is: $unApproved.id.IProflKey

Comment: This is technically iterating Arraylist of list object

Comment: In Velocity you can get information on objects by displaying their java class: `$unApprovedBook.class.name` ; this is often very useful when you're not sure about what happens.

Comment: @BrinzN if you want do get an answer you have to give more information. Im not sure even the values coming from the list?

Comment: Yes i tried iterating them in my java class and i am able to see the values. Iterator itr = unApprovedList.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext()) {
      Object[] arrObj = (Object[])itr.next();
      for(Object obj:arrObj) {
          System.out.println("Iterating array object in unApprpoved list:"+String.valueOf(obj));
      }
  }

Comment: [2/20/17 10:42:35:375 EST] 00000023 SystemOut     O Iterating array object in unApprpoved list:0000070022
[2/20/17 10:42:35:376 EST] 00000023 SystemOut     O Iterating array object in unApprpoved list:01000007002200000
[2/20/17 10:42:35:376 EST] 00000023 SystemOut     O Iterating array object in unApprpoved list:326
[2/20/17 10:42:35:376 EST] 00000023 SystemOut     O Iterating array object in unApprpoved list:111111111

Comment: Not sure how can i assign this values to a list which is a VO, so that i can add/ change few values and display that in UI

Comment: @ Claude Brisson: I tried your suggestion but its displaying as an object in UI